# How does one authenticate a production Docker Swarm on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, dockerhub

We have some servers which run a docker swarm.
On Docker Hub, we have some private repos we want to pull from our servers.
I personally think, that logging the the swarm master into my personal Docker Hub Account isn't a good idea. Especially, because I am an owner of our organisation.

So far, I haven't found any good solution with an rsa-key for example.

So I'm asking you: **Is there a way to pull private repos from a production docker swarm host, ideally without having to log in with my personal account?**

PS: I could possibly create another account with readonly rights and log into this account, although this sounds kinda hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a team/orgzanization account

Move all the private repos to that account namespace in DockerHub

Use that account for login to pull private images from DockerHub.

Workflow after creating team account:

> - docker login team-acount $TOKEN
> - docker pull/docker build/ docker push etc
> - docker logout

Comment: sorry, do I understand you right, when you say, that I have to create another Docker Hub Account and give him readonly rights? and then log into this account on my production server of corse..

Comment: you will need to setup a team account anyway , because it doesnt make any sense to have org private images namespaced under your personal name, you may explore other options for login in such as tokens etc but first you need team account/namespace

Comment: so there is no way to add a public key to docker hub and avoid creating another account?